# how is present string as object property in python?

Tags: python

I have an interesting question. I have class model:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    separation = models.ForeignKey(Separation, blank=True,
                                   null=True, default=None)
    number_card = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I can write:

```
patient = Patient()
patient.name = 'Saney'
```

But what should I do if I don't know what property I must changed. For example, the name of property what must changed come in the variable " property='name' ". But if I write next code:

```
patient.property = 'Saney'
```

python doesn't understand that I mean that I want write 'Saney' into patient.name and not to patient.property. And when I try to testing some thing, for example:

```
 patient.'name'= 'Saney'
```

python of course gave an error...)

Comment: Use `setattr(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setattr(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) for that:

```
setattr(patient,'name','Saney')
```

which is *equivalent* to:

```
patient.name = 'Saney'
```

The `setattr(..)` builtin has the following structure:

> **`setattr(object, name, value)`**
>
> This is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The
>   arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The **string
>   may name an existing attribute or a new attribute**. The function
>   **assigns the value to the attribute**, provided the object allows it. For example, **`setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`**.

Comment: it works, very big thak you))